# Reading & Writing data to a text file

Tags: java, file-writing

Writing a program to read a list of numbers, determine whether they are prime and then write those to a file. Posted this question earlier .. Fixed my logic to determine if the number is prime. Now I can't see to get it to write to the text file named "PrimeNumbers.txt"

At one point I had it able to write one line, but now nothing gets written to the text file. Please advise.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignFive_FileRead {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

int number; 
int count = 0;
int calc = 0;
int i = 2;

File myFile = new File("assignment5Numbers.txt");
File myTargetFile = new File("PrimeNumbers.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

System.out.println("** Checking for required files **");

// Check to see if file's exists

if (!myTargetFile.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Error: Unable to create target file!");
  System.exit(0);
} else {
  System.out.println("Target file has been created!");
}

if (!myFile.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Error: file cannot be found");
  System.exit(0);
} else {
  System.out.println("Source file has been found, starting operation...");
  System.out.println();
}

  // Reading numbers from text file
  while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
  number = inputFile.nextInt();

  while (i <= number / 2) {
     if (number % i == 0) {
        calc = 1;
     }
     i++;
  } // End second while loop

  if (calc != 1) {     
     count++;
     for (int x = 0; x <= count; x++) {
     PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("PrimeNumbers.txt");
     outputFile.print(number + "\t");
     outputFile.println("is prime");
     }
  } 

  // resetting variables for next check
  calc = 0;
  i = 2;

} // End first while loop

// System.out.println("Source file has a total of " + count + " numbers");

System.out.println("Data has been written to files.. Operation successful!");

 } // End main 
} // End public class
```

Comment: Flush and close the `outputFile`...

Comment: and also you need to check does myFile exist and if not create one before File myFile = new File("assignment5Numbers.txt");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. decalre your `PrintWriter outputFile` outside your `while` loop, you are going to reuse the `PrintWriter` and you want to keep its current contents/location in the file so it shouldnt be re-declared every time you parse another number. Also rename it, the name is not representative of what it does, call it something like `outputWriter`.
2. You need to `.close()` both your input and output streams, this ensures that the buffers have been flushed and resources are released from the Java application. Before the: `System.out.println("Data has been written to files.. Operation successful!");` put `outputFile.close();` and `inputFile.close();`

Comment: Thx, that worked.. Also I realized I didn't need to have a for loop